# JavaScript - Find and replace word in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I find a word (in this case a placeholder, e.g `_ORGAN_`) in an array and replace it with an element's value?

```
sql = new Array();

$('#system').change(function(){
    filter = " topography_index = _ORGAN_";     
    sql.push(filter);
});
```

In this case I would want to replace `_ORGAN_` with `$('#organ_menu').val();`

Comment: Do you want to replace in Array element which value is `_ORGAN_` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// sql array
var sql = ['organ not found', '_ORGAN_ is here'];
var val_to_replace = '_ORGAN_';
var replace_with = 'heart'; // temp value - change it with $('#organ_menu').val()

$.each(sql, function (key, val) {
    // search for value and replace it
    sql[key] = val.replace(val_to_replace, replace_with);
})

console.log(sql)
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8sZT/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do by iterating the array and  then assign the value to once it find its match.

```
for (i = 0; i < sql.length; i++) {
    if (sql[i] === "_ORGAN_") {
        sql[i] = $('#organ_menu').val();
    }
}
```

example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/z3u9a/) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate over the array and use replace on each element

```
var organValue = $('#organ_menu').val();

for (var i = 0; i < sql.length; i++) {
    sql[i] = sql[i].replace("_ORGAN_", organValue);
}
```

Comment: This works OK, but replaces only the first instance of _ORGAN_

Answer (score 1):

```
var regExp = new RegExp(organ, 'g');    
$.each(sql, function(index, value) {
    sql[index] = value.replace(regExp, 'test');
})
```

Comment: This works great when replacing multiple instances, so your solution givesme some flexibity...I'll probably use this...many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this, using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Defining_the_regular_expression_in_replace):

```
sql = new Array();

$('#system').change(function(){
    filter = " topography_index = _ORGAN_".replace("_ORGAN_", $('#organ_menu').val(), "gi");  
    sql.push(filter);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

First find the index of the item:

```
 var index=sql.indexOf("_ORGAN_");
```

Then insert your new item at that index and remove the first one:

```
sql.splice(index,1,newitem);
```

**[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**